# Are there any issues with MySQL's i18n(indic language) support?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, jdbc, internationalization, rdbms

We're evaluating MySQL and PostgreSQL for building our indic language(using utf-8 encoding) web application which will use MySQL or PostgreSQL.

One of my colleagues mentioned that MySQL had issues with i18n. I mostly come from the Oracle world and although I've played a lil with MySQL, I don't know enough to know that there are issues with its i18n support.

Does anyone know issues with MySQL's i18n support and if PostgreSQL would be better placed for building an application with indic language support(kannada, telugu, tamil, etc) using utf-8 encoding ?

Just so you know, we're going to be using J2EE to build this application and we will be using JDBC drivers to access the DB.

P.S : Will anything change if we were to use Rails to build the app instead of J2EE ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support the complete utf8-encoding:

> Currently, MySQL support for UTF-8
>   does not include four-byte sequences.

PostgreSQL has full support for utf8.

Comment: hi Frank,

  thank you. does MySQL has full support for 3-byte sequences ?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. I don't do MySQL anymore and don't know/remember everything about the details. Just use PostgreSQL and you're safe. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, mysql has no issues with languages.
Mysql don't deal with languages. Only with encodings.
You can use any encoding supported, and utf-8 is preferred one.

Comment: hi Col. Shrapnel,

  thanks for your comments. The intent was to use utf-8 encoding from the beginning. The question was "are there issues with i18n support with this encoding ?

Comment: @anjanb the whole world uses it.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel,

  That is what I thought. I'm still gunning for it . Since my colleague mentioned the issues, I'm doing "due diligence" instead of neglecting his warning. So,,,,

Comment: the whole world *should* use it.

Comment: Mysql's "utf8"  (not "utf-8") is a crippled implementation of the true UTF-8 encoding, it does not fully support the unicode standard (basically, does not support characters outside the BMP)